# move forward and turn right

Tags: arduino-uno

i have a project about making an obstacle avoiding robot. But this one is a bit special. I want the robot to move forward and when an object is close to it, to turn right. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfnzi.png

```
#define echoPin 7 // Echo Pin

#define LEDPin 13 // Onboard LED

#define m1a 4

#define m1b 3

#define ena 9

#define m2a 2

#define m2b 5

#define enb 8

int maximumRange = 200; // Maximum range needed

int minimumRange = 0; // Minimum range needed

long duration, distance=0; // Duration used to calculate distance


void setup() {

Serial.begin (9600);

pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);

pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT); // Use LED indicator (if required)

pinMode(m1a, OUTPUT);

pinMode(m1b, OUTPUT);

pinMode(m2a, OUTPUT);

pinMode(m2b, OUTPUT);

pinMode(ena, OUTPUT);

pinMode(enb, OUTPUT);

}
  void moveForward()
 {

 digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW); 

 digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);

 digitalWrite(m1b, HIGH);

 analogWrite(ena, 180);

 digitalWrite(m2a,HIGH);

 digitalWrite(m2b,LOW);

 analogWrite(enb,180);

 }
 void turnRight()

{


 digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH); 

 digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);

 digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);

 analogWrite(ena, 100);

 digitalWrite(m2a,HIGH);

 digitalWrite(m2b,LOW);

 analogWrite(enb,100);

 }

void loop() {

 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 

 delayMicroseconds(2); 

 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);

 delayMicroseconds(10); 

 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

 //Calculate the distance (in cm) based on the speed of sound.

 distance = duration/58.2;

if (distance <= maximumRange && distance >= minimumRange){
    turnRight();
}
else {
/* Send the distance to the computer using Serial protocol, and
turn LED OFF to indicate successful reading. */
 moveForward();
}

//Delay 50ms before next reading.
 delay(50);
}
```

Comment: m1a,m1b,m2a,m2b are the motor pins. ena, enb are the pwm pins from the driver(l298n). I am currently using an arduino uno, and hc-sr04 ultrasonic sensor and a l298n motor shield

Comment: Please edit your question (click "edit") and include the information from your comment in the body of the question.  Also, please edit your question and mark the code as code.  When including code in a stackexchange question or answer, first paste the code into the question or answer editing box; then in that editing box, highlight the code and press ctrl-k. Or highlight the code and click the {} icon in the toolbar at the top of the editing box. To highlight text click-drag across it or use the arrow keys while holding the shift key.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the robot to move forward and when an object is close to it, to turn right.

How close do you want the robot to be to the obstacle? You should at least declare some form of threshold to determine what values are considered "close". (Maybe a *closeThreshold* variable)

> while(distance>=maximumDistance) { moveForward(); if(distance<=maximumDistance) break; } turnRight();

As for the code you have posted, why not use a simple if else function with a *closeThreshold* variable instead of a while loop?

```
...
void loop() { 
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); 
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

 //Calculate the distance (in cm) based on the speed of sound.

 distance = duration/58.2; 
 if(distance<=closeThreshold) { 
 turnRight(); 
 } else {
 moveForward();
 }
}
```

Comment: oh well..the robot now is stuck right now.

Comment: Stuck as in not moving at all or stammering at a particular spot?

Comment: Not moving at all

Comment: I created a variable called maximumDistance, and if the current distance is smaller than that, the obstacle is considered close enough. It's the same with the closeThreshold variable

Comment: nope. it's not working at all

Comment: I made an edit in the source code and nothing happens. I made a function which calculates the currentDistance, but no results so far

Comment: Is there any values coming from the ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: Actually no. I mean i used the serial.print() function and it just displays text from the if statement in the serial monitor

Comment: OK...i tried with a sample code and now i get values from the sensor

Comment: Integrate your main code with the sample code, the robot should be able to move

Comment: So...i just did what you said. No results. With the sample code works as charm(The values come continuously and in the implemented version, they come one by one and the motors are just stuck)

Comment: http://arduinobasics.blogspot.nl/2012/11/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor.html this is the sample code

Comment: i removed the functions and tested the code just like that

Comment: I think the problem lies in your moveForward() and turnRight() function: you are delaying 1s everytime you call the function. So the whole loop delay would be ~1 second per cycle. Maybe reduce the delay in it?

Comment: Plus can you update the implemented version of code into the body of the question as an update? Easier to see what you have changed.

Comment: ok so...any ideas? removing the delay didn't work